# IllegalArgumentException in Eclipse AST

Tags: eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree

Here is question about Eclipse AST instrumentation. Below there I have a very simple code and this code throws **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException**. I indicated the line that the exception is threw.

Is there anyone who has an idea why this happens?

```
if(var.getRightHandSide().getNodeType() == Expression.INFIX_EXPRESSION){
    InfixExpression i1 = (InfixExpression) var.getRightHandSide();
    InfixExpression i2 = ast.newInfixExpression();

    i2.setOperator(InfixExpression.Operator.PLUS);
    i2.setLeftOperand(i1.getLeftOperand());  //Problematic line
    i2.setRightOperand(i1.getRightOperand());

    a.setRightHandSide(i2);
}
```

Comment: The first thing `InfixExpression.setLeftOperand` does is check if the argument expression is null and throws `IllegalArgumentException` if so. So check what `i1.getLeftOperand()` is returning.

Comment: i am sure it is returning. it is something about AST instrumentation I guess.